# jQuery image switcher: Uncaught TypeError

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make a jQuery image switcher. This is my HTML structure:

```
<div id="modal">
    <div id="colors">
        <ul class="product-image-thumbs">
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="thumb-0.jpg" id="thumb-0" class="gallery-image">
                </a>
             </li>
             <li>
                 <a href="#">
                     <img src="thumb-1.jpg" id="thumb-1" class="gallery-image">
                 </a>
             </li>
              <li>
                  <a href="#">
                      <img src="thumb-2.jpg" id="thumb-2" class="gallery-image">
                  </a>
             </li>
         </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="photo">
        <img src="current_img" id="1">
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery(".gallery-image").click(function(){
    $(".photo").prop("src", jQuery(this).prop("src"));
    return false;
  });
});
```

When I try the code I get the following error message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prop' of null
```

Does anybody know what is wrong with the code?

Comment: Well, for starters you're trying to set a `src` property on a `div`.  That's probably not going to work.  Aside from that, which object is `null`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `img` tag inside div do this way:

```
$(".photo > img").prop("src", jQuery(this).prop("src"));
```

[**Working Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/ehsansajjad465/rzs0aurw/)